# HSQL - dropping/creating types

Tags: sql, hsqldb

This should be simple but have yet to find an answer.

I want to create a type A only if it does not already exists and/or drop the type if it already exists and recreate it at the startup of my HSQL database.

Now I know the drop and create commands:

```
CREATE TYPE myType as VARCHAR(100)
DROP TYPE myType
```

However I have yet to discern how to check for the existence of the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually turned out to be very simple:

```
DROP TYPE myType IF EXISTS
```